# SlickJs problem with vertical slider when loading two slider with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am trying to use one slider code for two sliders using same class name. I have created this [codepen](https://codepen.io/xblack/pen/oNzNEKM?editors=1011) to illustrate the problem.

Problems:

1. Both sliders are not behaving same, means they have different sliding pattern. I have changed the color current active slide to show how both sliders are different.
2. One of the slider works fine ( till some slides) but other one totally off as you can see, in terms of container height, highlight pattern, etc.
3. Both of them have chopped content on top or bottom, even though there is no centerMode enabled. The behaviour I was expecting is to current slide to slide on the top and not show the preview of gone slide (top) and next (bottom)
4. Second slider changes its height randomly. I don't know why

I have tried one solution which didn't work either and it is there as commented code in the codepen.

```
$(".feature-container").each(function () {
      console.log(this.id);
      let elm_primary = $("#" + this.id)
        .find(".feature-slider")
        .get(0);  
        $(elm_primary).slick({
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,  
        focusOnSelect: true,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1000,
        vertical: true,   
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 700,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 4,
              slidesToScroll: 1,  
              focusOnSelect: true,
              autoplay: true,
              autoplaySpeed: 1000,
              vertical: true,
              dots: false,
              arrows: true
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    });
```

Comment: In your CodePen, you are using a `variableHeight` option, which I don't believe exists. You may want to set a consistent height for your slides and a height on your slideshow that matches the height of 4 of the slides.

Comment: @Ed thanks for the reply. I have tried with and without variableHeight, both didn't work. Also variableHeight does exist. It wasn't in the official document but I have seen that as a solution for some question related with slickJS on stackoverflow. I may be wrong.

Comment: I didn't find any references to it in the code on GitHub, but there is an issue wherein people are discussing workarounds: https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/issues/1803